# Filter nested model attributes in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models: Users and PaymentMethods, the association between this models is:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payment_methods, dependent: :destroy
end

class PaymentMethod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true 
end
```

I want to loop in each user and see in an attribute of PaymentMethod, named 'period_end_date'. so I do this:

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |u|
  u.payment_methods.last.period_end_date
end
```

I'm getting this error => NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_methods' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation

The error is shown because I have 2 test users, in the first user there is still no data in the attribute 'period_end_date' and association exist, but is empty, in the second user there is data in the attributes, if I say, u.payment_methods.last.period_end_date I get => Wed, 13 Jun 2018 (only in the second user)

I want to filter in my loop only the users who has data in PaymentMethod attributes for get rid of => NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_methods' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation

How I do this?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's triggering the error? The error looks more like you're doing `User.all.payment_methods` or `@users.payment_methods`; `User.all` or `User.where(...)` will give you a `User::ActiveRecord_Relation` instance.

Comment: Yes, I had also thought the same, in the DB only the second user has data on payment_method table. so, in the loop `@users = User.all` `@users.each { |u| u.payment_methods.last.period_end_date }` but the first user has no data in payment_method, is nil. `@users.first.payment_methods.empty? # => true`

Comment: So the `NoMethodError: undefined method 'payment_methods' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation` error isn't really relevant? You want to get the users that have payment methods so that you can `u.payment_methods.last.period_end_date` without running into `nil`s?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the problem with a simple rails app: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1724892 if you run this with `ruby rails.rb` it doesn't error.

However, if you create a user without any payment_methods, the code does error. See https://gitlab.com/snippets/1724893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to filter in my loop only the users who has data in PaymentMethod attributes for get rid of => NoMethodError: undefined method `payment_methods' for User::ActiveRecord_Relation

The actual problem seems to be you have users without payment methods (see my comment on your question).

You have some options, depending on *how* you're going to use the results.

1) You can filter out users without payment methods when you query them from the database like this:

```
@users = User.joins :payment_methods
```

2) If `@users` must include users that without payment methods, you can skip them when looping like this:

```
@users.map do |user|
  next unless user.payment_methods.any?
  user.payment_methods.last.period_end_date
end
```

3) You can guard by checking for `payment_methods` before calling `.last`.

```
User.all.map do |user|
  user.payment_methods.last.period_end_date if user.payment_methods.any?
end
```

4) You can add a `period_end_date` method to the user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def period_end_date
    payment_methods.limit(1).pluck :period_end_date
  end
end
```

5) push #4 into the association by extending it with a helper method

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payment_methods, class_name: 'PaymentMethod' do
    def last_period_end_date
      last.period_end_date if any?
    end
  end
end
```

which you can call like this

```
User.all.map do |user|
  user.payment_methods.last_period_end_date
end
```

If you're really *only* concerned about `PaymentMethod`s without a `period_end_date` then try this:

6) You can still filter users when you query them from the database

```
@users = User.joins(:payment_methods).where.not(payment_methods: { period_end_date: nil })
```

7) This can be simplified a bit by pushing the `where.not` conditions into a scope of the `PaymentMethod` class:

```
class PaymentMethod < ApplicationRecord
  scope :period_ends, -> { where.not period_end_date: nil }
end
```

and merging it

```
@users = User.joins(:payment_methods).merge PaymentMethod.period_ends
```

#### Notes

- `payment_methods.last` doesn't specify an order, you should set one (either as part of this chain, when you specify the association, or with a default scope) otherwise the order is up to your database and may be indeterminate.
- chain `.includes(:payment_methods)` to eager load the payment methods and avoid n+1 queries
- it sounds like a nil `period_end_date` could be invalid data. Consider adding a validation / database constraint to prevent this from happening

Comment: WOW! I did not expect that help, thank you man, I really appreciate your help, I'm currently going for option 6, `@users = User.joins (: payment_methods).where.not (payment_methods: {period_end_date: nil})`, this magic line helped me a lot , my users are now filtered and I finally get rid of the error. In the registration flow, if someone does not complete the payment method, I will not have to worry about that.